# Is there a way to get list of errors in chrome/firefox which happened throughout the web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an html file which may contain many **img** tags and also it will have JS like below.
[image: html file]

If I try to load this page in chrome and also click the button **clickMe** I get the below errors in console.[image: error file]

I know that using **window.onerror** I can handle/capture ReferenceError and may be save it for later. But, is there any error stack from where I can get all the list of errors which has happened during the life-cycle of the web page. Because, I am not able to capture **ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND** error.

Please let me know whether it is possible and if so how ?

Comment: Your websites logging system (if available) should have the capability of reporting most errors including 404. Therefore, if you need to use it, move your error log file into a readable directory and parse from there.

Comment: Other than that there is no way, you are saying ?

Comment: No, there are many ways of capturing errors depending on what types of errors they are. In your example, its a 404 error which will be logged by the server and retained as defined by your config.

Answer (score 1):

ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error is not JS error so it can't be caught globally, only way send ajax file existing request. Also for image you can use onerror event to caught this error, for audio you can use source tags and etc.. But for globally there is no way to catch it.
Also for queueing error I'm recommending use [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understand your question.  However, if you want to catch your javascript error and log to the console do like this:

```
try {
    dosomething...
}
catch(err) {
    console.error(err.message);
}
```

There are 4 level of logging to the console:

```
console.error(message); 
console.log(message); 
console.warn(message);
console.info(message);
```

On the Console tab of the Firebug tool in Chrome, you can filter out the type of logging.  You can click on the Preserve log checkbox so all the log will continue to append to the console.

Other errors report from the browser, that is those you don't capture from your script, also go here.

If you really want to capture an image load fail there are couple ways to do it.  One way is something like this:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" onerror="console.error('Fail to load smiley.gif');" />
```

See this link if you want to enable debug to a file for google chrome: https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging